# howto setup codelite for existing git project

Tags: c++, git, codelite

I have an existing c++ project with multiple source directories configured in git, but my workspace/project does not recognise any existing source files.

How can I auto-configure a workspace+project in codelite ?

```
./application/abc/include      // h files
./application/abc/src          // cpp files
./application/def/include
./application/def/src          // with 15+ application subset directories.
```

Comment: The application has a directory structure like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ workspace does not automatically sync with the file system (only `Node.js` and `PHP` workspaces)

However, it does contains a feature that allows you import all the files and directories from the file system to the workspace view (it does not physically copy the files, only add their path to the workspace XML file)

[This wiki page](http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/WorkingWithCMake) explains how to do this in details with screenshots

You did not mention your OS and CodeLite version, but just in case, make sure you are using the latest CodeLite available for your OS (the minimum is CodeLite v9.0.0)

Check our [download page](http://downloads.codelite.org) to ensure that you are using the latest:

The **GIT** plugin will automatically detect that your workspace is under git source control and will adjust its view to fit your local repo.

Eran

Comment: OS Fedora 22, Codelite 9.0.0

Comment: The git plugin works nicely, and I've viewed code differences using it. It would be a real nice feature if I could create the projects / workspaces from existing git project & cmake build files. codelite is on backburner while I do important stuff

Comment: The only way I found (so far) was to create a project and then import the relevant files from that directory into that project. This is slow with many projects.

Comment: I am working on a new workspace type for custom build systems (such as `QMake` , `CMake` etc which will be much faster). Hopefully it will make it to CodeLite 9.1